# How to use wildcards with ls without listing directory contents?

Tags: macos, command-line, unix, ls

ls typically displays only the files and folders in the present directory. But once you add a wildcard it starts searching in sub-directories.

example:

```
$ ls
fight_folder    file1       file2

$ ls f*
file1   file2

fight_folder:
file3
```

How do you limit the scope to only the current directory?
Using OS X

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`ls -d` suppresses listing the contents of directories listed on the command line (via the wildcard). From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/ls.1.html):

> **-d**      Directories are listed as plain files (not searched recursively).

Comment: ls -d * does what you say but unfortunately ls -d does not list directories.